# Dynamically create different buttons with ajax server side datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

This is the table;

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Process</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and here is the javascript ;

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "ServerSideProcessor.aspx",
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,  
                "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>PAY</button>"
            }]
        });

        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            alert(data[1] + " is recieved.");
        });
    });
```

What I need is create different type of buttons in "Process" coloumb, for example ;

```
"columnDefs": [{
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,  
               if(data[5]=='1')
                "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>PAY</button>"
               else
"defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>UNPAID</button>"
            }]
        });
```

How can I accomplish that ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to define the output like this:

```
"render": function ( data, type, full) {
   if(full[5] == '1'){
        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>PAY</button>";
    }else{
        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>UNPAID</button>";
    }
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/L6omgf1y/3/).  I've changed the condition to make it work with the dummy data, but you get the idea.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir!